# Mongodb find contains, startswith, endswith, and exact string with java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to do a find on my database for strings. These strings contain a wildcard for contains, startswith, and endswith; otherwise I just search for the exact value. I've looked at many examples of doing search with java but they all seem to be outdated with the current java driver and use BasicDBobjects which I cant get to work. I believe the code below will work 
I just need to know how I need to change some of the strings to search the database:

Let's say my database looks like this

```
{State:Ohio}
{State:Iowa}
{State:Texas}
```

containsString: returns any document that contains it. ie "io" would return Ohio and Iowa documents

beginString: returns any documents that start with it. ie "io" would retun Iowa document

endString: returns  any documents that end with it. ie "io" would return Ohio document

else it will look for the exact value. ie "texas" would return Texas document

```
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("database1");
MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection("collection1");
BasicDBList list = new BasicDBList();
for(int i=0; i < data.length; i++){
     String[] queries = data[i].split(":", 2);
     String column = queries[0];
     String query = queries[1];
     if (query.startsWith("*") && query.endsWith("*")) {
        String containsString = query.replace("*", "");
        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(new Document(column, containsString)).iterator();
       while (cursor.hasNext()) {
          list.add(cursor.next());
       }
     } else if (query.startsWith("*")) {
       String beginString = query.replace("*", "");
       MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collecton.find(new Document(column, beginString)).iterator();
       while (cursor.hasNext()) {
          list.add(cursor.next());
       }
     } else if (query.endsWith("*")) {
       String endString = query.replace("*", "");
       MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(new Document(column, endString)).iterator();
       while (cursor.hasNext()) {
          list.add(cursor.next());
       }
     } else {
       MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(new Document(column, query)).iterator();
       while (cursor.hasNext()) {
          list.add(cursor.next());
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: Your existing code appears to be simply stripping off the `*` wildcard chars. Convert your search strings into regular expressions that you can use with [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex).

Comment: That is for the mongo shell but I need a way to do it with the java driver. However I have found the filter option with the java driver so I provided my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I figured I might have to do regex for this but I didn't how I would using the java driver. However, I've now found that the java driver has [filters](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/builders/filters/)(more [documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html) on them). So I guess this has now turned into a how do I transform my strings into regex question.

And so after some learing of the regex ways, this is what I did.

For contains

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*"+Pattern.quote(anyString)+".*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collecton.find(regex(column, pattern)).iterator();
```

For startswith

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^"+Pattern.quote(beginString), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(regex(column, pattern)).iterator();
```

For endswith

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(endString)+"$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(regex(column, pattern)).iterator();
```

For exact

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?<=\\s|^)"+Pattern.quote(query)+"(?=\\s|$)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(regex(queryCol, pattern)).iterator();
```